# How to apply a size for ElasticSearch filtered query?

Tags: elasticsearch

For regular query size works ok:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 2
}
```

returns 2 results. But when I try to add a filter by geo_polygon:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_polygon": {
          "coordinate": {
            "points": {
              "points": [
                [
                  -84.293222919922,
                  33.865223592668
                ],
                [
                  -84.293222919922,
                  33.632776407332
                ],
                [
                  -84.482737080078,
                  33.632776407332
                ],
                [
                  -84.482737080078,
                  33.865223592668
                ],
                [
                  -84.293222919922,
                  33.865223592668
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 2
}
```

it always returns 10 results and looks like it ignores "size" parameter completely. Are there are any specific approaches to make "size" work for filtered query?

MacOS,

elasticsearch

```
version: {
    number: 1.0.1
    lucene_version: 4.6
}
```

Comment: would specifying `size` before the `query` parameter change anything? or otherwise, use it as request parameter?

Comment: specifying size before the query parameter does not change anything but it works as a request parameter.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine in version 1.2.1 running on Ubuntu:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        ...blah...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: strangely, it wont work if you place from and size after the query{}!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems this also works if you put the size parameter inside the query parameter.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        ...blah...
      }
    },
    "size": 100
  }
}
```